# PayPal double payment

Tags: paypal

I need to charge a credit card 50% on booking and the rest of 50% on a later date. Is there any other option beside recurring payment? This is only a two time payment so not like any subscription.

Any suggestions are welcome, I feel like recurring payments option is to complicated for this and as I know a recurring payment has no obligation to be paid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reference transaction could do this. It would work like this

You charge your customer the initial booking fee. You record the transaction ID from Paypal.
Within 90 days (not sure if this has changed) you would then call (in the Classic API anyways) [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) with your original transaction ID. Note that you WILL have to accept that the CVV2 (which neither you nor Paypal can store due to PCI compliance) will not match (at least in my experience). It's not a huge risk since the first transaction likely had to pass that check but it is a caveat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is if I don't store the security code how am I able to charge the card the second time?

Comment: You have to ignore the CVV2 error. In our case, we have to turn off the fraud settings and run it, then turn them back on again. But we have really old fraud settings too.